# Anyway to do Hibernate reverse engineering without putting foreign key in objects

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Anyway to do Hibernate reverse engineering without putting foreign key in objects.

I am trying to do a Hibernate reverse engineering on my mysql database but I dont want the objects to show foreign keys..  Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You would like the generated code to not contain @ForeignKey annotations? Show what the generated code is like, and show how you would like it to be.

Comment: yes. I just want copies of the tables, table fields etc not keys

Comment: Now it's even more obscure what you want. Show what the generated code is like, and show how you would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same problem here, you should use a new acces to this DB where alter table is not allowed.

So: create a new user with a DBA not add alter table permission and use this connection parameter to acces to this DB, this way alter table will not possible!
(workaround i know)

And the cause can be for this workaround e.g. Liferay doesn't use foreign keys and if hibernate mess up the table, the whole system fall apart...